# Unresolved reference: asLiveData while converting Flow to LiveData

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm

I have the following situation:

There's my repository class:

```
import com.mikhailovskii.timesapp.util.Result
import kotlinx.coroutines.delay
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.flow

class LoginRepository {

    fun fetchUser() = flow {
        emit(Result.Loading)
        delay(1000)
        emit(Result.Success((0..20).random()))
    }

}
```

There's ViewModel class:

```
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import com.mikhailovskii.timesapp.util.Result

class LoginViewModel() : ViewModel() {

    private val loginRepository = LoginRepository()

    private val a = loginRepository.fetchUser()


    val user: LiveData<Result<Int>> get() = loginRepository.fetchUser().asLiveData()

}
```

And there's Result class:

```
sealed class Result<out R> {

    data class Success<out T>(val data: T) : Result<T>()

    object Loading : Result<Nothing>()

    object Error : Result<Nothing>()

}
```

So, when I try to convert the Repository's Flow to the LiveData with the help of `asLiveData` method, `asLiveData` is underlined and studio writes that it's an unresolved reference. But I cannot understand why does it happens, as repository returns Flow. So, how what's the problem and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 105, accepted):

I think you are missing the LiveData dependency.

```
def lifecycle_version = "2.2.0"

// LiveData
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
```

[Documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle)

Comment: Not working on version 2.2.5. Do you have input for this?

Answer (score 23):

You are missing a dependency:

```
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.2.0"
```

(or any higher version)